# How to fix gomod: `github.com/stretchrcom/testify@v1.4.0: parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "github.com/stretchr/testify"`

Tags: go, go-modules

When I do a `go mod tidy`.
I got the following error:

```
go: github.com/stretchrcom/testify@v1.4.0: parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "github.com/stretchr/testify"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due a package referring to testify before it was moved to `github.com/stretchr/testify`.

The solution is to add the following line in your `go.mod`:

`replace github.com/stretchrcom/testify v1.4.0 => github.com/stretchr/testify v1.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

If this is a direct dependency, then would suggest adding the correct dependency directly to your `go.mod` file i.e. [github.com/stretchr/testify v1.4.0](https://search.gocenter.io/github.com~2Fstretchr~2Ftestify/info?version=v1.4.0)